# Implementing open tracing (datadog) with Scala Futures

Tags: scala, datadog, opentracing

this is my attempt at implementing open tracing (with datadog) but I am running into the issue where if this function is called with high concurrency, the spans on datadog start mixing together (i.e. spans for different operation names coalesce into 1 span). I have a suspicion this has to do with context switching between threads but would anyone know be able to point me in the right direction? Thanks

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DZCCyl8WRoOBgeragoDbXQ

Comment: Your whole problem lies in your reliance on "activated span" which can only be one of many "existing spans" in same scope. I think this is the same code which you shared on Reddit few days back. And this has too many issues as explained in Reddit thread.